How can I specify an optional argument for \item in a biblatex bibliography driver
I want to write a bibliography environment in biblatex based on enumitems' description environment lists (I want to do this because it fits in with other parts of the document I'm building). Like itemize, description uses an optional argument to item for the description label. I want to write my bibliography environment so that the year of publication is set in this optional argument. This seems like it should it work, but doesn't (I've used itemize instead of description here to make the example as minimal as possible):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[date=year]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo,
  title = {SomeTitle},
  author = {Doe, John},
  date = {2024-04-27},
  journaltitle = {Great Works}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{description}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  [\printdate{}]%
  \newunit%
  \printfield{title}%
  }

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=description]

\end{document}

Instead of interpreting the printed date in square brackets as an optional argument to the \item call which precedes it, this prints the square brackets themselves as part of the list. I.e. I want my bibliograhy typset as if this were happening:
\begin{itemize}
\item[<year>] <other stuff>
\end{itemize}

but instead I'm getting it as if this is happening:
\begin{itemize}
\item[] [<year>] <other stuff>
\end{itemize}

How can I get the former and not the latter?

You can add the optional argument in \defbibenvironment. It's too late in the driver (hidden under lots of grouping layers, so that \item won't see the optional argument properly).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[date=year]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{description}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}
  {\item[\printdate]}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo,
  title        = {SomeTitle},
  author       = {Doe, John},
  date         = {2024-04-27},
  journaltitle = {Great Works}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=description]
\end{document}


